# Why is doesn't the tangent exist in this case?

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to find whether a vertical tangent exists at x=0 for $y=x^{2/3}$. 
Now, $x=y^{3/2}$. dx/dy is clearly defined for x=0 and is equal to zero. Why doesn't this imply that a vertical tangent exists at $x=0$. 
Note: It can be proved by using approaching both sides of a function via a limit that the tangent does not exist.

Comment: If you have the proof then why do you ask? The proof is the answer. If you don't understand the proof, then show us the proof. However, assuming this function is given in parametric form, then maybe $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a singular point in which all derivatives vanish. Reparametrizing this curve might give you the desired tangent.

Comment: @m.winter I want to know why dx/dy=0 does not imply that a vertical tangent exists at x=0. Since dx/dy is the rate of change of x wrt y, if it is zero, it should mean a vertical tangent exists at x=0

Comment: Assuming $y$ is a function $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, then vertical tangents are just no thing one can talk about. To define a tangent you need the derivative of $y$ at $x=0$, but it does not exist because it diverges $\to\pm\infty$. This can be seen as a vertical tangent in some sense, but usually is not. To understand what exactly is your teminology, I need you to write down the proof you mentioned. One problem might be that the limit from the left will give you $-\infty$ and a limit from the right will give you $+\infty$. This will give you "vertical tangents" but one is rising and one is falling.

Comment: The meaning of $x^{2/3}$ is not quite obvious for negative $x$, so if you want to consider your function on $\mathbb R$ (instead of $[0,\infty)$ as Βασίλης Μάρκος assumed in his answer), you need to specify precisely what your function looks like in $x<0$. That must be done  _before_ you consider the inverse function $x(y)$, because the inverse might _not exist_ if $y(x)$ is not injective...

Comment: @CiaPan If it is a real function, then it is uniquely defined for $x<0$. Right?

Comment: That is exactly the problem. The limits from the right and left are giving +infinity and -infinity hence the tangent can't be defined

Comment: Of course it can! Limit $+\infty$ makes a vertical tangent pointing upwards, and $-\infty$ makes a vertical tangent pointing downwards. And those two are exactly _the same vertical line_.

Comment: Assuming your function is defined as $(x^2)^{(1/3)}$ see the graph at Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F3)+for+x+in+(-0.01,+0.01)

Comment: @xasthor Right, they can't be defined in the usual ways. What exactly is your question? You already gave the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit of the derivative $+\infty$ makes a vertical tangent (or, in general, asymptote) pointing upwards, and $-\infty$ makes a vertical tangent pointing downwards. And those two are exactly *the same vertical line*.

So YES – a graph of your function has a vertical tangent at $x=0$.

Comment: Just mentioning that usually a derivative of $\pm\infty$ is not conidered to induce a tangent because the corresponding tangent would be $y(x)=\pm\infty x$ which is not a valid function.

Comment: @M.Winter That's irrelevant here. We know that IF a continuous real function $f$ is defined on some open interval AND it has a (finite) derivative at some point $p$ in the interval, THEN the function's graph $\{(x,y): y=f(x)\}$ has a tangent at $(p, f(p))$. However, that says nothing about existence of a tangent when $f'$ does not exist at $p$. Hence _'is not conidered to induce a tangent'_ is vacuously true: not because of meaningless $\pm\infty\,x$ but because of the antecedent of the implication being not satisfied.

Comment: You are right. However, whether this should be considered a tangent line to $f$ is really subjective. It depends on what is your definition of a tangent. Usually a tangent is said to "touch" a function in some point. Something I would not say for this example.

Comment: @M.Winter How about a tangent to a graph of $y=x^3$ at zero then...?

Comment: That is not a "cusp" as in the case of OPs function.

Comment: Is there any anti-cusp clause in a definition of a tangent line?

Comment: As I said, I do not know a universally accepted definition of tangent line. Most likely your approach will work for many definition fo tangent. But it look strange "visually".

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function with $$f(x)=x^{\frac{2}{3}}$$ Let us calculate:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x}}=+\infty$$
so, by definition, the function $f$ has a verical tangent at $x_0=0$, the line $x=0$.

**Edit:** Should we have deifined $f$ over $\mathbb{R}$, then we would also have:
$$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\dots=-\infty$$
So, $f'(0)$ would not exist ($f'$ not defined at $x_0=0$) however - after @CiaPan's comment - the vertical tangent does exist.

Comment: You changed the question. F(x) is defined over all real numbers

Comment: Edited it properly. Also, when you find the tangent of $x=y^{\frac{3}{2}}$, you are working in another axis system, so the tangent at $x_0=0$ over there is not vertical, as well.

Comment: If limit is $\pm\infty$ then the vertical tangent may exist! Compare $y=\sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I got confused for a second. I'm sorry for the misconception

Comment: I like the verb _'to deifine'_ :)

Comment: Haha! It might be Dei-Fine (Fine in italics means end, so it could be a hint for world's end).

Comment: I had something like 'deification' in my head, but your interpretation is fine, too. P.S. In italics or in Italian...?

Comment: Well, that headache is having impact both at my writingand at my thought... It's Italian, of course...

Answer (score 0):

The function
$$f(x):=x^{2/3}\qquad(x\geq0)$$
is not differentiable at $x=0$. But this does not mean that the curve
$$\gamma:\quad x\mapsto\bigl(x, x^{2/3}\bigr)\qquad(x\geq0)$$
has no tangent at $(0,0)$. We may as well present this curve in the form
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto {\bf z}(t):=\bigl(t^{3/2},t\bigr)\qquad(t\geq0)\ .$$
Here $$\dot{\bf z}(t)=\left({3\over2}t^{1/2},1\right)\qquad(t\geq0)\ ,$$
with $\dot{\bf z}(0)=(0,1)$. This shows that the tangent of $\gamma$ at the origin is vertical.

Comment: But OP requires the function to be defined on all reals, not just non-negatives.

Comment: @CiaPan: The OP is not specific about this. In my view the expression $x^{2/3}$  is only defined for $x\geq0$. I'd write $f(x):=\bigl|x^{2/3}\bigr|$ for the graph in your picture.

Comment: The description of the problem actually isn't very precise, but see the last sentence – OP says _'by using approaching both sides of a function'_ there. If I get it correctly, that means both one-side limits can be calculated, hence the function is defined on both sides of zero.  
Additionally see the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2357244/why-is-doesnt-the-tangent-exist-in-this-case#comment4855648_2357269) under the answer by Βασίλης Μάρκος, who assumed $x\ge 0$, too: _'You changed the question. F(x) is defined over all real numbers'_

Answer (score 0):

(1) If the graph looks like this

[image]

is it considered that there is a vertical tangent at 0?

(2) Or, if the function is complex (non-real) for $x<0$ is it considered that there is a vertical tangent at 0?

(3) If the function is undefined for $x<0$, is it consdered that there is a vertical tangent at 0?

(*) Which of these cases is your question about?